# Foreach loop not given expected output

Tags: php, foreach

i have two arrays
**$getusersdetails**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [users_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [users_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [users_id] => 4
        )

)
```

and $data['checkbox']

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
```

I want to insert this values to mysql database. so itried

```
 $j=1;
        foreach ($getusersdetails as $userstatus):

            $val1['fk_c_id'] = $data['checkbox'][$j];
            $val1['fk_user_id'] = $userstatus['users_id'];
            $val1['status'] = 1;
            $result1 = $this->db->insert('admin_course_details', $val1);
              $j++;
        endforeach;
```

here i din't get expected output.
Expected output

```
status | fk_c_id | fk_user_id
1             1     2
1             1     3
1             1     4
1             3      2
1             3      3
1             3      4
```

my output

```
status | fk_c_id | fk_user_id
    1             1     2
    1             1     3
    1             1     4
```

I want 1 and 3 (checkbox values) for each users,so here i have 3 users.but here only 1 check box value is inserting.Any help is appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply two `foreach()`

```
foreach ($data['checkbox'] as $data):
  foreach ($getusersdetails as $userstatus):
      $val1['fk_c_id'] = $data;
      $val1['fk_user_id'] = $userstatus['users_id'];
      $val1['status'] = 1;
      $result1 = $this->db->insert('admin_course_details', $val1);
  endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Comment: @Ezra  glad to help you :):)